# About the Gronwall inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inequality, gronwall-type-inequality

If I have that $$||\eta_u(t)||\leq 1+C_1\int_0^t \frac{1}{||\eta(s)||}||\eta_u(s)||ds$$  and $$\sqrt{1-\frac{2\varepsilon}{C}}||u||\leq ||\eta(s)||\leq 2||u||$$ how to obtain using the Gronwall inequality that $$\displaystyle ||\eta_u(t)||\leq 1+\exp\left(\frac{2C_1}{||u||}t\right)$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From your norm estimation you have
$$
\frac{1}{||\eta(s)||} \leq \sqrt{\frac{C}{C-2\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{||u||} \leq 2\frac{1}{||u||},
$$
for $\varepsilon < \frac{3}{8}C$. Therefore,
$$
||\eta_u(t)||\leq 1+C_1\int_0^t \frac{1}{||\eta(s)||}||\eta_u(s)|| \,ds \leq
1+\frac{2 C_1}{||u||}\int_0^t ||\eta_u(s)|| \,ds
$$
Using [the Gronwall inequality in integral form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) (and noting that $1$ is non-decreasing function:) we arrive to
$$
||\eta_u(t)||\leq \exp^{\frac{2C_1}{||u||}t} \leq 1 + \exp^{\frac{2C_1}{||u||}t}.
$$